# How i use preg_replace php function in mysql

Tags: php

how to use `preg_replace` in MySQL query.

`"SELECT *  FROM video_master WHERE preg_replace( '/\s+- /', ' ', trim($title))"`

Answer (score 0):

You need use like this

```
$pattern = "/\s+- /";
$title= preg_replace($pattern,'',$string);
$query = " SELECT *  FROM video_master WHERE column = '$title';";
```

Comment: I run ur query but it shows  #1305 - FUNCTION video_db.preg_replace does not exist. AM using InnoDb

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use sprintf:

```
$pattern = "/\s+- /";
$query = sprintf("SELECT *  FROM video_master WHERE column = '%s';", preg_replace($pattern,'',$string));
```

sprintf is always good for MySQL queries in PHP, you avoid create the incorrect dinamic queries, also I recommend you to use mysql_real_escape_string function, this function scapes the special characters of MySQL like apostrophe.

```
$pattern = "/\s+- /";
$query = sprintf("SELECT *  FROM video_master WHERE column = '%s';", mysql_scape_real_string(preg_replace($pattern,'',$string)));
```

With this function and sprintf, you reduce the risk of a bad behavior or SQL injection attack in your application.

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.